# How to access fingerprint and fingerprint algorithm for DTLS handshake

Tags: javascript, webrtc, dtls

I am working on a WebRTC gateway project and I have a need to access a browsers fingerprint and its algorithm from Javascript. I would like to access this information to send it via a WebSocket signaling channel. I expected to get the fingerprint and hash algo via the browsers answer SDP, but on chrome its missing.

I have searched for an answer and have had no luck.

Here is a screen shot showing the information I want to access (via webrtc-internals):
[image: fingerprint]

I'm looking for a cross-browser solution, but if it works in Chrome only for now that would be just fine. The parameters I want are shown in the image as "googFingerprint" and "googFingerprintAlgorithm".

**Update**: screen shot of the offer
[image: sdp offer with sha-1]

**Update**: screen shot of the answer
[image: sdp answer]

**Update**: latest offer + answer
[image: sdp offer with sha-256]

Comment: The hashed finger print is in the SDP exchange in chrome and firefox. Example `a=fingerprint:sha-256 34:AD:87:74:2A:C4:64:BB:56:D4:96:56:89:FE:31:B6:AF:43:A8:BB:2C:CD:B1:8C:FB:18:DB:9C:0C:D1:0F:3C` It is hashed using sha-256. Do you not see this line in your SDPs? [Here is some SDP help](http://webrtchacks.com/sdp-anatomy/)

Comment: Unfortunately in the answer the fingerprint attribute is absent (see new image)

Comment: Does the offer have one? If it doesn't, chrome may not think the session is dtls

Comment: Yes, the offer had a fingerprint attribute for audio and video

Comment: could you post the offer SDP as well? This is some sneaky bug because Chrome is supposed to have the fingerprint attribute in both the offer and the answer.

Comment: ok offer posted, i also noticed that chrome adds an extra candidate at the bottom; its not there on the server side dump (may be another unrelated bug in chrome)

Comment: I see an issue, the hashing algorithm needs to be `sha-256`, your finger print attribute in the offer states that it used `sha-1`

Comment: Switching to sha-256 didn't fix this, the fingerprint is still absent in the answer

Comment: You are not saying you will accept an incoming or outgoing connection for DTLS. Only incoming. Try `actpass` for your `a=setup` attribute.

Comment: Same result with setup actpass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no known way to access the fingerprint via javascript in the browser. There is a known chrome issue directly related to this question (that I submitted). https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=417949